# SQL Server Connection string for azure failover groups

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, nhibernate, azure-sql-database

I have set up a failover group and have tried to connect using NHibernate to .database.windows.net as the server URL but it says "No such host is known". I can connect to the individual servers that make up the failovergroup using the same connection string which looks like this:

```
Server=tcp:XXXXXXproductionbackupfailovergroup.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXXXXXX;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Trusted_Connection=False;
```

I can attach to tcp:XXXXXXproductionbackupfailovergroup.database.windows.net,1433 using SSMS if I specify the database in options so I know the failover group exists

In each of the sql servers I have allowed my IP address through the firewall. As I understand what they are saying here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview I should be able to use the above as my connection string.

This connection string to a single instance of the two databases works: Note they are virtually the same.

```
Server=tcp:XXXXXXproduction.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXXXXXX;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Trusted_Connection=False;
```

Comment: Is the Issue solved for you ?

Comment: If it is resolved, please add it as an answer that could help more communities easily to search .

Comment: No, failover connection string does not work.

Comment: Are you using Primary or Secondary user credentials in failover group connection string?

Answer (score 0):

In the portal UI, under "Auditing and Threat Detection" for your databases, is  "Auditing Type" set to "Table (depreciated)"? If so, this needs to be set to "Blob".

There is an issue where failover groups can't be connected to in some instances if Auditing Type is set to Table (deprecated). After encountering a connection issue, adjusting this setting meant we could the connect to a failover group endpoint URL.